# HTTP Caching, User Authentication and PHP

Tags: php, http, caching, http-caching

I'm working on some software in PHP and I'm in the process of trying to make it utilize HTTP caching effectively. However, one of the problems I've been having lately is after logging in, pages visited prior to logging in are cached and do not act as if logged in.

This is especially a problem if there were to be an HTTP cache between PHP and the client. If I set the cache limiter to always be 'public,' the page presumably will always be cached (even by a proxy cache.) If I set the cache limiter to be 'public' when not logged in, and 'private' when logged in, the problem I currently have would probably still occur. If I set the cache limiter to always be private, a proxy cache would not benefit at all, AND the problem I currently have would probably still occur.

What is the ideal solution to this problem? Is there a way to cause the web browser 'try again' after the user has logged in? For a proxy cache, I know there are ways to cache based on the incoming cookies, so I believe that may solve part of the problem. But what about the issue from the web browser point of view?

Comment: Would `must-revalidate` or `proxy-revalidate` be the magic keyword here?

Comment: Oh, I forgot about `must-revalidate`... you may be right. I do believe, though, that it causes nginx (as a caching proxy) to not cache. What do I do about that? I'd like to use nginx here.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken. I read up upon the subject (because I never remember these by heart) and it only means that the cached copy must be revalidated after the copy becomes stale.

Comment: Oh, alright. I'm going to do more research in the meantime. Thanks for trying, though.

Comment: Just as a thought... Are you providing an ETag with your Expires/Last-Modified headers? You could rehash the ETag with the logged in user's ID (or similar) or simply not server one for logged in users. Although I guess aggressive proxies in the middle might still be problematic.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a great solution here but you have a couple options:

1. Make the pages truly identical whether your user is logged in or
   not, by utilizing AJAX to request the logged in state via a JSON
   service.
2. Don't cache the pages, just cache the scripts, styles, and images. Browser caching of the HTML is only helpful if your users are constantly looking at the
   same pages and not expecting different results. Is this your
   use-case? If it is is, you're probably using AJAX already to provide
   real-time updates and it's probably not a huge leap to implement
   option #1.